# AngularJS unable to Load data from Service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, nvd3.js

I am having trouble sending data to controller from a service that calls an api. I have used http://embed.plnkr.co/jEQMch/ as a sample application and modified it to create a bullet chart.

My controller looks like this:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['nvd3', 'gridster', 'plunker.services']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $timeout, DataService) {
  $scope.gridsterOptions = {
        margins: [20, 20],
        columns: 4,
        mobileModeEnabled: false,
        draggable: {
            handle: 'h3'
        },
        resizable: {
     enabled: true,
     handles: ['n', 'e', 's', 'w', 'ne', 'se', 'sw', 'nw'],
    },
    };

 $scope.options = {
            chart: {
                type: 'bulletChart',
                transitionDuration: 500
            }
        };

  $scope.data = {}

    $scope.dashboard = {
        widgets: [  
      {
            col: 0,
            row: 0,
            sizeY: 3,
            sizeX: 2,
            name:"Test",
            chart:  
             {
              options: DataService.bulletChart.options(),
              data: DataService.bulletChart.data(),
              api: {} 
            } 
          },
    ]
    };

  // We want to hide the charts until the grid will be created and all widths and heights will be defined.
  // So that use `visible` property in config attribute
  $scope.config = {
    visible: false
  };
  $timeout(function(){
    $scope.config.visible = true;
  }, 200);
});
```

and my dataservice looks like this :

```
angular.module('plunker.services', [])
.factory('DataService', function($http, $q) {
    return{
      bulletChart: {
            options: bulletChartOptions,
            data: bulletChartData
            } 
        };

/**
     *  Data & Options Generators
*/
    function bulletChartOptions() {
      return {
            chart: {
                 type: 'bulletChart',
       margin : {
                    top: 40,
                    right: 20,
                    bottom: 0,
                    left: 130
                },     
                showValues: true,
                duration: 500,
            }
        }
    }
    function bulletChartDataTest() {
        return   {
            "title": "Test",
            "subtitle": "Completed",
            "ranges": [200,400,709],
            "measures": [694],
            "markers": [300]  
            } 
        }

    function bulletChartData(){
            $http.get('http://myapi/data').then(function(response) {
                   console.log('response-dataFound',response.data);
                  //$bulletChart.data = angular.copy(response.data);
                  return response.dat
                  ;})


                }

});
```

In my service, if I use function "`bulletChartDataTest`" , I get the correct graph:
[image]

When I switch to `bulletChartData`, I get no graph. 
I think `data: bulletChartData` is not working correctly. What's wrong in my `bulletChartData` method? Any pointers ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because in `bulletChartDataTest` data is already available & you're just returning it. But in `bulletChartData` you're making actual service call which actually returns a promise. So, as you're defining data along with config options on load, as call to dataservice is asynch in case of bulletChartData, it's failing & it's not refreshing even after successful returning of data. So what you can do is call the service on load & have the data in scope variable of controller, and then attach that variable to `data` attribute of `nvd3` directive on view. So this way as soon as response come from service data will automatically updated for chart & it'll be created on in DOM.

```
    <nvd3 options="widget.chart.options" data="chartData" api="widget.chart.api" 
          config="config" events="events"></nvd3>
```

And in controller make service call to get chart data like:

```
DataService.bulletChart.servicedata().then(function(data){
    $scope.chartData = data;
});
```

Here servicedata is factory function to make real service call.

Your version of working plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/WG6PJO?p=preview

Comment: I do have a question on this. How do I extended this to add  a new graph ?  Say I have another graph with json data. I wont be able to use data="chartData" in that case.

Comment: I created this plunker with two data set in bulletData.json  https://plnkr.co/edit/ssYa4HQBYOTq7OsasLA0?p=preview , Graph takes only second dataset for both the graph.

Comment: @ProgSky https://plnkr.co/edit/A9UGduhC9Y9sPWVtCZ9x?p=preview Just assign data in widgets array.

Comment: Thanks again @Shantanu